# How do I display the following HTML code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

The following was given to be as an example an outlook email.

I have an iframe, and is putting this text as the iframe's srcdoc. It works for most of the content examples I have tested so far, but this particular example shows nothing.

I realise there is very little to show, but how can I get something that looks more like an email?

```html
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
    <meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 14 (filtered medium)">
    <style>
        <!--
        /* Font Definitions */
        
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Cambria Math";
            panose-1: 2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;
        }
        
        @font-face {
            font-family: Calibri;
            panose-1: 2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;
        }
        /* Style Definitions */
        
        p.MsoNormal,
        li.MsoNormal,
        div.MsoNormal {
            margin: 0in;
            margin-bottom: .0001pt;
            font-size: 11.0pt;
            font-family: "Calibri", "sans-serif";
        }
        
        a:link,
        span.MsoHyperlink {
            mso-style-priority: 99;
            color: blue;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        
        a:visited,
        span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed {
            mso-style-priority: 99;
            color: purple;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        
        span.EmailStyle17 {
            mso-style-type: personal-compose;
            font-family: "Calibri", "sans-serif";
            color: windowtext;
        }
        
        .MsoChpDefault {
            mso-style-type: export-only;
            font-family: "Calibri", "sans-serif";
        }
        
        @page WordSection1 {
            size: 8.5in 11.0in;
            margin: 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;
        }
        
        div.WordSection1 {
            page: WordSection1;
        }
        

    </style>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>  <o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />  </xml><![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>  <o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">  <o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />  </o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
</head>

<body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple>
    <div class=WordSection1>
        <p class=MsoNormal>
            <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no content in this document, just an empty paragraph - what do you expect?

Comment: an email type layout?

Comment: Email is either plain text or whatever you define in HTML / CSS, so what is an email type in your opinion? And what should an empty page display in case it is an email layout?